# Handling Admin Dashboard Authentication

Tags: php, oop, authentication

I am currently working on getting better at OOP. I am working on an app that requires you to log into in order to access, therefore, the only unprotected page would be the "login" page.

I am wondering what the best way of approaching this is. I would like to keep this as object-oriented as possible. Should I create an auth class, or method within my user class, and then check against that at the top of all of the files I want to protect?

Or create a single routing file and try and implement the logic there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Auth class is much better. You can use it for all type of user login authentication. Frameworks are doing in that manner almost.